# Comandos CMD WINDOWS

Tags: windows, cmd, prompt

Não sei se vocês podem tirar dúvidas sobre este assunto, porém estou com dificuldades de abrir o arquivo de forma contínua no CMD do Windows.

Quando utilizo o Linux basta fazer isto:

```
tail -f C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log
```

Porém no Windows esse comando não funciona. Alguém sabe me informar o similar a este ou outro que faz a mesma função de permanecer com arquivo aberto para verificar as escritas simultânea?

Comment: Seria melhor você dizer qual o objetivo que quer atingir com o Cmd, pois nem todo mundo sabe como o tail -f funciona. "Abrir de forma contínua" não é exatamente uma maneira tão clara de descrever o follow. Isso facilitaria para quem tem apenas domínio de CMD para te ajudar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça isso com o [Windows PowerShell](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=windows%20powershell&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=SUy1VtfFFsaIwgSq2ruYBA), é apenas fazer esse comando:

```
Get-Content C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log -Wait
```

Se quiser mesmo usar o `tail` do Linux, pode instalar o [GNU Libraries for Win32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/).